Distance between two points equal to zero
The following URL:
(https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/35.8287027,10.6402266;35.8281954,10.6412867) gives me the distance = 0.
{
    "code": "Ok",
    "routes": [
        {
            "geometry": "a{r_AwnmyE??",
            "legs": [
                {
                    "steps": [],
                    "summary": "",
                    "weight": 0,
                    "duration": 0,
                    "distance": 0
                }
            ],
            "weight_name": "routability",
            "weight": 0,
            "duration": 0,
            "distance": 0
        }
    ],
    "waypoints": [
        {
            "hint": "ov5mh67ZR4gYAAAAAAAAAGMCAADUAAAAqszXQQAAAAAm1ylEB6tqQxgAAAAAAAAAYwIAANQAAACiGwAA2SEiAo6NoQDfsyICY1uiAAcAfwezPETB",
            "distance": 7120.60930065,
            "name": "",
            "location": [
                35.791321,
                10.587534
            ]
        },
        {
            "hint": "ov5mh67ZR4gYAAAAAAAAAGMCAADUAAAAqszXQQAAAAAm1ylEB6tqQxgAAAAAAAAAYwIAANQAAACiGwAA2SEiAo6NoQDjsSICh1-iAAcAfwezPETB",
            "distance": 7185.535760288,
            "name": "",
            "location": [
                35.791321,
                10.587534
            ]
        }
    ]
}

But when I check on the site Openstreetmap, I find 198 meter.
https://www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=fossgis_osrm_car&route=35.82818%2C10.64138%3B35.82879%2C10.64025#map=19/35.82851/10.64087
Can you please help me? I tried to extract distance between two points.
